# TinyMCE plugin - prevent user from deleting specific content

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am working on a plugin for Tinymce to use in Silverstripe 4.

It is a footnote - plugin to create `<sup>` tags with continuous Numbers.

The footnote - text is stored in a div (.footnoteContainer) at the end of the editor content within a ordered list.

The creation and editing of the footnote is handled on the word itself (edit Link | delete Link). with a window (editor.windowManager.open).

I am struggling with this function:

I am trying to prevent the user to delete the .footnoteContainer or its content when keydown backspace. that's working if the container itself was selected. But it does not work if a `<li>` Footnote - Text `</li>` in the container was selected.

Thats my fuction (with a lot of tries and errors).....

please have a look:

```js
editor.on('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8) { // backspace / delete


    var selection = editor.selection.getSel();
      console.log('selection = ' + selection);
    var target = editor.selection.getNode(); //e.target;
      console.log('target = ' + target.className);
    var footnoteContainer = editor.dom.select('.footnoteContainer')[0];
    var fNC = editor.dom.select('.footnoteContent')[0];
    var fND = editor.dom.select('.fndiv')[0];

    var isFootnoteContainer = target === footnoteContainer || footnoteContainer.contains(target) || footnoteContainer.contains(fNC) || footnoteContainer.contains(fND);
    var isContent = target === fNC;
    var isDiv = target === fND;

    if (isFootnoteContainer || isContent || isDiv) {
      console.log('it is fnContainer!');
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

and the footnote html :

```html
<div class="footnoteContainer"><br />
     
  <ol id="fNol">
    <li>
      <div class="fndiv"><a id="1681202707036" class="footnoteContent"></a><a href="#1681202707036_back">Footnotetext 1</a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="fndiv"><a id="1681215616710" class="footnoteContent"></a><a href="#1681215616710_back">Footnotetext 2</a></div>
    </li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

on pressing backspace how can i adrdess the `<li>` - tag or the `<div>` - tag or the `<a>` tag ?

Comment: While you are creating this for use in a silverstripe site, this question has nothing to do with silverstripe. In future please refrain from adding tags that aren't directly related to the problem you want help with.